# Plugin function not pulling data

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently working on a plugin. As such, I inserted a block of code in the header with a function. The code is supposed to be pulling data from custom fields but it returns empty tag. However, it works if I add it directly to the header. Any ideas what the problem is? My code looks like below.

```
<?php 
function pyramid() {
  ?>
<meta name="description" content="<?php $desc = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'description', true); if($desc) { echo $desc; } else { 

    // do nothing; 

} ?>" />
<?php
}; 
add_action( 'wp_head', 'pyramid' );

?>
```

It returns the result below when added through the plugin.

```
<meta name=description content>
```

Comment: do you have description field in post meta?

Comment: @Vel Yes I do. And, it works if I pull it directly on the headers.

Comment: Try adding `global $post;` at the start of your pyramid function.

Comment: @Mr.Me That did it. Thanks so much!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`global $post;` needs to be added to the pyramid function.

Alternatively you can also use `get_the_ID()` instead of `$post->ID`

Also, if you wanted to, you can shorten your pyramid function to just

```
function pyramid() {
    global $post;
    ?><meta name="description" content="<?= get_post_meta($post->ID, 'description', true) ?: '' ?>" /> <?php
}; 
add_action( 'wp_head', 'pyramid' );
```